# In my react application I face some issues

Tags: reactjs

In my react application I link one page to another but the another page is starts in middle but I want it to start from the top.

I tried scrollrestoration but it is not working.
I also checked my css but I dont understand how to solve it

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new component and import in `App.js` or `index.js`

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function ScrollToTop() {
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }, [pathname]);

    return null;
}
```